# The given functor from Vect to Set is representable by $A \in Ob Vect$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Let $S$ be a set. Define functor $F$ from $Vect$ (real vector spaces) to $Set$ where vector space $W$ is mapped to the set of maps from $S$ to $W$, so $W$ here is treated merely as a set. Prove that functor $F$ is representable by an object in $Vect$.

We were just given the definition of a representable functor, namely $F:C\rightarrow D$ is representable if and only if there is an object $A \in Ob C$ and an element $a\in F(A)$ such that for every element $x\in F(X), X\in Ob C$ there is a unique morphism $\alpha:A\rightarrow X$ for which $x=F(\alpha)(a)$. This is a lot to unpack and I am expected to understand and answer the above question within $48$ hours, any help would be much appreciated from those who work with category theory - I am extremely new to the field.

Comment: I can't believe this "definition" is all you've been given. Do you know any examples of representables?

Comment: @КряжевАрсений unfortunately I do not have any examples because the professor just wrote this on the board and said "now you can do the question". I found a nicer looking definition which says that a functor $F:C\rightarrow Set$ is representable if there exists a natural isomorphism of F with a functor $hom(A, -)$ for some $A \in ob C$.  If we used this definition in the thread then I think thats ok as well because it looks much nicer.

Comment: Yes, that's the definition. Can you solve the problem using this one?

Comment: @КряжевАрсений honestly I don't think I can by myself because this is pretty abstract and I'm having a really hard time in this category work

Comment: You are given the functor $W \mapsto \operatorname{Set}(S,UW),$ where $UW$ is $W$ regarded as a set. And you need to exhibit it as a functor of the form $W \mapsto \operatorname{Vect}(V_S,W)$ for some vector space $V_S$. So your task is to find $V_S$ such that a ("natural") bijection holds between $\operatorname{Set}(S,UW)$ and $\operatorname{Vect}(V_S,W)$ for any $W$.

Comment: Hint: what data determines a vector map $\mathbb{R}^3 \to W$? What data determines a set map $\{0,1,2\} \to W?$

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:** A map $S\to W$ can be considered as a selection of $|S|$ (not necessarily distinct) elements $w_s$ of $W$, indiced by the elements $S$.

Consider an $|S|$ dimensional vector space $A$, and fix a basis $b_s$ indiced by elements of $S$.
Use that any function to a vector space whose domain is a basis, extends uniquely to a linear map.